# Having difficulty in using Solve with a system of simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to use `Solve` on a system of relatively simple test equations as shown below, but empty braces `{}` with no solutions are being produced as a result, even though there are eight solutions to this system, one solution being $ u = 1, v = 0, w = 1, x = 0 $ for example. I would appreciate any help in understanding why this isn't working as expected. Thanks.

*Note: These equations have been revised since the original post.  There were two instances of the use of a variable c in the last equation which should have been q, which incorrectly added another variable, and which affects some of the earlier answers. Apologies.*

```
eqns = {u == u^2, v == v^2, w == w^2, x == x^2, q == q^2,
        u + w - 2u*w == 0,
        q == u*w,
        4v*x*q - 2*v*x - 2*v*q - 2x*q + v + x + q == 1};
Solve[eqns, {u, v, w, x}]
```

Comment: It helps to add a domain `Integers` to `Solve`, over which the equations are solved.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ there are a couple non-integer solutions though

Comment: @ElliotG For interested variables $ (u, v, w, x) $ it seems no noninteger solutions?

Answer (score 5):

The point is, that `Solve[eqns, {u, v, w, x}]`  looks for solutions that are valid for all possible c and q. That is none, therefore {},

`Solve[eqns,{u, v, w, x, c, q}]]`  tries to find solutions for all given variables. That's not possible for two of the solutions, therefore the message `Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables`  .

`Solve[eqns]`   looks for as many variables as possible.

`Solve[eqns,{u, v, w, x, q}]` without c finds only the two solutions that are valid for all possible c.

`Solve[eqns, {u, v, w, x}, {c,q}]`  does explicitly ignore the values of c and q and therefore gives solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Solve for all variables, automatically:

```
Solve[{u == u^2, v == v^2, w == w^2, x == x^2, q == q^2,
       u + w - 2 u*w == 0, q == u*w,
       4 v*x*c - 2*v*x - 2*v*c - 2 x*q + v + x + q == 1}]

(*    {{q -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 0, w -> 1, x -> 0},
       {q -> 0, u -> 0, v -> 0, w -> 0, x -> 1},
       {c -> 0, q -> 0, u -> 0, v -> 1, w -> 0, x -> 0},
       {c -> 1/2, q -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 0},
       {c -> 1/2, q -> 0, u -> 0, v -> 1, w -> 0, x -> 1},
       {c -> 1, q -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 1}}    *)
```

Comment: I wonder why you get an error then if you include $c$ and $q$ as in `Solve[{...},{u,v,w,x,q,c}]`

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Reduce`

```
Reduce[{u == u^2, v == v^2, w == w^2, x == x^2, q== q^2,u + w - 2 u*w == 0, q == u*w, 4 v*x*c - 2*v*x - 2*v*c - 2 x*q + v + x + q == 1}
, {u, v, w, x}]
(*(q == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && w == 0 && x == 1) 
|| (q == 1 &&u == 1 && v == 0 && w == 1 && x == 0) 
|| (q == 0 && c == 0 &&u == 0 && v == 1 && w == 0 && x == 0) 
|| (q == 0 && c == 1/2 &&u == 0 && v == 1 && w == 0 && x == 1) 
|| (q == 1 && c == 1/2 &&u == 1 && v == 1 && w == 1 && x == 0) 
|| (q == 1 && c == 1 && u == 1 && v == 1 && w == 1 && x == 1)*)
```

The option `Backsubstitution -> True` shows the possible solutions

```
(Reduce[ gln , Backsubstitution -> True]// ToRules)
(*Sequence[
{x -> 0, w -> 1, v -> 0, u -> 1, q -> 1}, 
{x -> 1, w -> 0,v -> 0, u -> 0, q -> 0}, 
{x -> 0, w -> 0, v -> 1, u -> 0, q -> 0,c -> 0}, 
{x -> 0, w -> 1, v -> 1, u -> 1, q -> 1,c -> 1/2}, 
{x -> 1, w -> 0, v -> 1, u -> 0, q -> 0,c -> 1/2}, 
{x -> 1, w -> 1, v -> 1, u -> 1, q -> 1,c -> 1}]*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides adding domains, there is another undocumented (?) usage of `Solve`:

```
Solve[eqns, {u, v, w, x}, {c, q}]
```

which solves for `u`, `v`, `w`, and `x`; and simultaneously specifies `c` and `q` as suppressed variables.

> ```
> {{u -> 1, v -> 0, w -> 1, x -> 0}, {u -> 0, v -> 0, w -> 0, x -> 1}, {u -> 0, v -> 1, w -> 0, x -> 0}, {u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 0}, {u -> 0, v -> 1, w -> 0, x -> 1}, {u -> 1, v -> 1, w -> 1, x -> 1}}
> ```